# Dynamic styling in react native using config file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, reactive-programming

I intend to use a main config file like the app.json and load it at app startup, where I add a key value for the app name. Based on the app name I need to apply styles from that app directory style config file. I do not have any requirement that the changes should be applicable at runtime too. It is just going to be once at startup. Is this possible without using an npm module?

Comment: basically you want to apply style which in file right ?

Comment: Yes, based on the name of the app, that will come from app.json, I will need to pick the right config style file and apply it in components.

Comment: You can import JSON files using `import` / `require`, but that would require that you ship the JSON file to wherever you deploy the app so it can be read at runtime. You could instead write the config at build time, but how to do that is dependent on how you build your app.

Answer (score 1):

Create two js file eg styleSheet1 and styleSheet2 with this pattern:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var myStyle = React.StyleSheet.create({
   style1: { },
   style2: { }
)}

module.exports = myStyle;
```

Add a variable to identify the app as per name

```
var appName='App1';
var customStyle;
```

Add the following condition

```
componentWillMount() {

   if(appName=='App1'){
    customStyle = require('./styleSheet1');
  }else{
    customStyle = require('./styleSheet2');
  }
}
```

And then as per condition the component will take the style

```
<View style = {customStyle .style1} />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
import JSONStyles from 'path/appStyles';

...

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  Object.assign({}, JSONStyles, {
    localStyle: {
      ...
    },
  })
);

...

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.localStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.importedStyle}></Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is a working example (with imported JS object, not a plain JSON file):
https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/importing-styles